# How do we reorder a linked list- reversing the second half and connecting every adjacent element to the first half one by one?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am writing code to solve LeetCode's [Reorder List](https://leetcode.com/problems/reorder-list/) code challenge:

> You are given the head of a singly linked-list. The list can be represented as:
>
> L<sub>0</sub> → L<sub>1</sub> → … → L<sub>n - 1</sub> → L<sub>n</sub>
>
> *Reorder the list to be on the following form:*
>
> L<sub>0</sub> → L<sub>n</sub> → L<sub>1</sub> → L<sub>n - 1</sub> → L<sub>2</sub> → L<sub>n - 2</sub> → …
>
> You may not modify the values in the list's nodes. Only nodes themselves may be changed.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: head = [1,2,3,4]
> Output: [1,4,2,3]
> ```
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> ```
> Input: head = [1,2,3,4]
> Output: [1,4,2,3]
> ```

Here is my code:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class Solution:
    def reorderList(self, head: ListNode) -> None:
        
        def reverseLL(curr): 
            curr = head 
            counter = 0
            #finding the mid=point of the LL
            while curr: 
                curr=curr.next 
                counter+=1 
            if counter%2==0: 
                counter= counter//2 
            else: 
                counter = (counter//2) +1
            #this is to make curr2 point at the middle node or the node after the middle
            curr2 = head
            while counter >=0: 
                curr2=curr2.next
                counter -=1
            return curr2
            
        #reversing the second half of the LL (curr2 points to middle node or node after middle if counter is odd)
        prev = None
        node = reverseLL(head)        
        while node:
            curr_reverse = node.next 
            node.next = prev
            prev = node
            node = curr_reverse            
        #prev is at this point the head of the reversed second half of the linked list 
        #now we do the reordering 
        curr = head 
        prev_nex = None
        while prev_nex: 
            nex= curr.next
            curr.next = prev 
            prev_nex = prev.next
            prev.next=nex
            prev=prev.nex
            curr=nex 
        return head
```

When I write this out with pen and paper and run any input through it, it works, but for some reason it fails the test, in particular for `input=[1,2,3,4]`, it produces `output=[1,2,3,4]`

Can anyone spot any inconsistencies? I have added comments to describe what I am trying to do at each stage of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following issues:

- The final `while prev_nex:` loop is never going to iterate since `prev_nex` is initialised as `None` just before starting the loop. The condition could be fixed with `while curr and prev:`
- The one-but-last statement has a typo: `prev=prev.nex` should really be `prev=prev_nex`
- The `while` loop in `reverseLL` is iterating too many times. It should stop two nodes earlier. Currently it stops at the last node when the list is [1,2,3,4], while it should really stop at the one with value 2 (or with some other changes, at node 3). I would suggest `while counter > 1:` here, as then no other changes are needed to the code.

With these three fixes, your code will work.